# What Is The Meaning of $\{\|X_{n}-Y_{n}\|>\varepsilon\}$?

Tags: notation

Unfortunately I've forgotten some notation I came across recently. Can someone clarify what is the meaning of what is shown in the red box?[image]

The book is Probability Essentials by Jacod-Protter.

Comment: @kimchilover Then is it the same as $f(X_n)-f(Y_n)=1$ if $||X_n-Y_n||>\epsilon$ and 0 $f(X_n)-f(Y_n)=0$ if $||X_n-Y_n||\leq\epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|X_{n}-Y_{n}\|>\varepsilon$ is notation for the set $A:=\{x\in\Omega:\|X_{n}(x)-Y_{n}(x)\|>\varepsilon\}$. Thus, $1_{\{\|X_{n}-Y_{n}\|>\varepsilon\}}$ is the indicator function of the set $A$. I.e., 
$$
\begin{aligned}
1_{\{\|X_{n}-Y_{n}\|>\varepsilon\}}(x)&=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if }x\in A\\
0 &\text{ if }x\notin A
\end{cases}
\\
&=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if }\|X_{n}(x)-Y_{n}(x)\|>\varepsilon\\
0 &\text{ if }\|X_{n}(x)-Y_{n}(x)\|\leq\varepsilon
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, $E\{|f(X_{n})-f(Y_{n})|1_{\{\|X_{n}-\|Y_{n}\|>\varepsilon\}}\}$ is the expected value of the function $g(x)$, where

$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
|f(X_{n}(x))-f(Y_{n}(x))| &\text{ if }\|X_{n}(x)-Y_{n}(x)\|>\varepsilon\\
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ 0 &\text{ if }\|X_{n}(x)-Y_{n}(x)\|\leq\varepsilon
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: So it is a product? Like $E\{|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\}1_{||X_n-Y_n||>\epsilon}=0$ if $||X_n-Y_n||\leq \epsilon$ and $E\{|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\}1_{||X_n-Y_n||>\epsilon}=E\{|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|\}$ if $||X_n-Y_n||> \epsilon$.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think it is, in effect, what your are saying.